# Changing the numbering in Chemnum

Tags: counters, chemnum

How do can you change the numbering in the chemnum package? I would like to start from 100 rather than 1 for chapter 1. Then start from 200 for chapter 2 etc.

Comment: Can you prepare a small example document with two chapters and some chemnum figures? That makes it easier for potential answerers to try out solutions.

Answer (score 2):

To quote the chemnum documentation:

> **7.2  Reset the Numbering**
>
> There are cases when it actually might make sense to reset the counting of the compound labels. For this you can
>   use this command:
>
> `\resetcmpd[<integer>]`  (Default=1)
>
> Reset the
>   numbering for main compound labels to start with `<integer>` again.
>   This is the same as `\setcounter{cmpdmain}{<integer>− 1 }`[...]

A MWE incorporating this could be the following:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{chemnum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{first chapter}
\setcounter{cmpdmain}{99}
\cmpd{H2O} \cmpd{HCl} \cmpd{H2SO4}

\chapter{second chapter}
\setcounter{cmpdmain}{199}
\cmpd{NH3} \cmpd{NaOH} \cmpd{KOH}

\end{document}
```

For a more automated solution, you could also make use of the `etoolbox` package as follows:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{chemnum}
\usepackage{etoolbox,calc}

\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\@makechapterhead}{\setcounter{cmpdmain}{100*\thechapter-1}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{first chapter}
\cmpd{H2O} \cmpd{HCl} \cmpd{H2SO4}

\chapter{second chapter}
\cmpd{NH3} \cmpd{NaOH} \cmpd{KOH}

\end{document}
```